# Switching Regulator Ground Moating

Tags: ground, isolation, switching

I have a DC-DC switching regulator that operates at switching frequency of 260Khz that steps down a 28vdc to 3.3Vdc.
On the same PCB I have a microcontroller and would like to have it's ground plane to be as clean as it can be from any switching regulator noise .

Will a ground moat around the microcontroller helps in this case? I will have a 15mil trace that connects the switching regulator ground to the microcontroller ground. 
Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: After I read this [EMC design guideline](http://learnemc.com/tutorials/guidelines/Important_Guidelines.html), I started having a second thought on this practice. Design guide#2 clearly says that it's rare that you need a moat. I am a bit confused now, will I still need a moat in my case?. Can you anyone shed some light on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat the switching regulator as having its own little ground plane - it's almost to be regarded as a stand-alone circuit so my advice is keep the moat around the power supply circuit and don't allow inputting power feeds to the switcher to route via any other ground/rail.

It could be that keeping the moat around the microcontroller has the same effect but as we don't know the full extent of your circuit I have adopted what I feel is the more appropriate way of looking at the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Would you add a ferrite bead to connect the microcontroller ground to the switching regulator ground?

Comment: I probably wouldn't do that.